# How can I display asp textboxes horizontally?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, webforms

How can I make ASP textboxes be in a horizontal form?
I want to know the code that will enable my textboxes to be in a straight line horizontally and not vertically.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
                <h2 class="form-signin-heading" style="color: #355171; text-align: center; font-weight: 500; font-size: 13pt; margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom: 5px;">LOGIN</h2>
                <div id="dvMessage" runat="server" visible="false" class="alert alert-danger" style="margin-bottom: 1%;">
                    <strong><i class="fad fa-exclamation-square" aria-hidden="true" style="margin: 0 7px; font-size: 14pt;"></i>&nbsp;</strong><asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Font-Size="10pt" />
                </div>
                <label for="txtUsername" style="font-weight: 500;">Email</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" OnTextChanged="Button1_TextChanged" Font-Size="11pt" placeholder="Email Address" Width="100%" />
                <br />
                <label for="txtPassword" style="font-weight: 500;">Password</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control" Font-Size="11pt" placeholder="Password" />
                <a href="#" style="color: #075481; float: right; font-weight: 500; font-size: 10pt;">Forgot Password?</a>
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" BackColor="#32657c" Text="Login"/>
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both, ASP and HTML textboxes are inline elements normally. In a new webform with empty template in ASP.NET just move into design tab and place a new Textbox. Click somewhere else, but remain inside the div, so that no control remains selected. Your cursor would be after the Textbox you just created, and the div is showing focus. Pick and drop another Textbox now. If everything is going correct, You will see two textboxes side by side.
No extra coding or css property required.

Here is a post by Microsoft

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/creating-a-basic-web-forms-page#to-add-controls-to-the-page

In the Microsoft's post above, you can instead of placing a button, place a textbox.